# Create matrix from dataframe in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have dataset of following:

```
> iris
   X5.1 X3.3 X1.7 X0.5 X.1
1   6.1  3.0  4.6  1.4   1
2   4.8  3.1  1.6  0.2  -1
3   5.0  3.4  1.5  0.2  -1
4   4.5  2.3  1.3  0.3  -1
5   5.4  3.4  1.7  0.2  -1
6   5.1  2.5  3.0  1.1   1
7   5.5  2.6  4.4  1.2   1
8   4.8  3.4  1.9  0.2  -1
9   6.5  2.8  4.6  1.5   1
10  5.4  3.0  4.5  1.5   1
11  5.8  4.0  1.2  0.2  -1
12  5.0  3.3  1.4  0.2  -1
13  7.0  3.2  4.7  1.4   1
14  5.0  3.4  1.6  0.4  -1
15  4.7  3.2  1.6  0.2  -1
16  5.0  2.3  3.3  1.0   1
17  4.4  3.0  1.3  0.2  -1
18  5.0  3.0  1.6  0.2  -1
19  4.9  3.0  1.4  0.2  -1
```

Now, I want to create matrix called "train.x" and it should store 10 rows and 4 columns from the given dataset. How would i do that? My solution so far is

```
train.x<-matrix(iris[1:70,1:4])
```

and it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated thanks!!

Comment: `as.matrix(iris[1:70,1:4])`?

Comment: linked to this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/16913071/3871924

Comment: Thanks that worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
 as.matrix(iris[1:10, 1:4])

#   X5.1 X3.3 X1.7 X0.5
#1   6.1  3.0  4.6  1.4
#2   4.8  3.1  1.6  0.2
#3   5.0  3.4  1.5  0.2
#4   4.5  2.3  1.3  0.3
#5   5.4  3.4  1.7  0.2
#6   5.1  2.5  3.0  1.1
#7   5.5  2.6  4.4  1.2
#8   4.8  3.4  1.9  0.2
#9   6.5  2.8  4.6  1.5
#10  5.4  3.0  4.5  1.5
```